# Measure the quality of text for text analysis after cleaning

Tags: r, quanteda

Is there any measurement which could help to see if the quality of text for text analysis techniques after cleaning process has better results for example for lsa from quanteda.textmodels.

Example from the package:

```
library(quanteda.textmodels)
library(quanteda)
library(stm)
quant_dfm <- dfm(data_corpus_irishbudget2010,
                 remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE,
                 remove = stopwords("english"))
```

and if I use

```
quant_dfm2 <- dfm(data_corpus_irishbudget2010,
                 remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE
                 remove = stopwords("english"))
```

How is it possible to measure the performance (which is better)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the upcoming version of **quanteda** (available on Github), `textstat_summary()` is added. You can use it to check how clean the texts are:

```
library(quanteda)
library(quanteda.textmodels)
quant_dfm <- dfm(data_corpus_irishbudget2010,
                 remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE,
                 remove = stopwords("english"))
textstat_summary(quant_dfm)

#                     document chars sents tokens types puncts numbers symbols urls tags emojis
# 1        Lenihan, Brian (FF)    NA    NA   4157  1549      0       0      75    0    0      0
# 2       Bruton, Richard (FG)    NA    NA   1824   855      0       0      18    0    0      0
# 3         Burton, Joan (LAB)    NA    NA   2938  1371      0       0      49    0    0      0
# 4        Morgan, Arthur (SF)    NA    NA   3175  1349      0       0      42    0    0      0
# 5          Cowen, Brian (FF)    NA    NA   3107  1376      0       0      38    0    0      0
# 6           Kenny, Enda (FG)    NA    NA   1848   959      0       0      20    0    0      0
```